# Получение двоичного представления числа в c#

Tags: c#

Вот есть, простой код для получения двоичного числа, как я понял, число 315 преобразуется в String и выводит в двочном виде.

```
int x = 315;
Convert.ToString(x, 2)
```

Вот еще есть другие виды преобразования, которые я нашел на другом форуме, но для меня они кажутся более сложными и не очень правильными. До конца не могу понять, что тут происходит. Буду очень благодарен за разбор!

1.

```cs
int[] num = new int[1];
num[0] = 315; // Ваше число
BitArray ba = new BitArray(num); // ba будет содержать в себе массив флагов

// Вывод числа в двоичном представлении
//
for (int i = 0; i < ba.Length; i++)
{
      if (ba[i])
         Console.Write(1);
      else
         Console.Write(0);
}
```

2.

```cs
        public static string FuncTo2(int chislo)
        {
            if (chislo == 1)
                return "1";
            else
                return FuncTo2(chislo / 2) + (chislo % 2);
        }
```

3.

```
    public static string FuncTo2(UInt64 chislo)
    {
        return (chislo == 1)?"1":FuncTo2(chislo >>= 1) + (chislo & 1);
    }
```

4.

```cs
            BitArray bitarray = new BitArray(64);
            bitarray[3] = true;
            byte[] bytearray = new byte[8];
            bitarray.CopyTo(bytearray, 0);
            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToInt64(bytearray,0));
```

Comment: @nick_n_a Объяснить четыре куска кода :).

Comment: @Igor, да, все верно )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- `BitArray` содержит массив булева типа => условие в цикле перебора для того, что бы напечатать либо 0, либо 1 в зависимости от `True/False`

2,3 по сути одно и тоже. Суть в том, что выполняется деление на основание новой системы счисление, т.е 2. Далее складываются все остатки снизу вверх+результат последнего деления- это и будет переведенное число.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4- какая-то непонятная мне магия.

Comment: 4 - Это преобразование в другую сторону. Из массива битов, один из которых (индех 3) взведен, получают длинное целое с значением `8`.

Comment: 4- преобразование с помощью библиотеки для работы с битами `BitArray`. Почти то же самое что 1, только с использованием ф-ций массового копирования.

Comment: @iluxa1810, Igor, nick_n_a. Благодарю всех вас, теперь стало лучше понятно, что происходит в этих кусках кода.